# How do I parse arabic sentence using Stanford core nlp

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have pretty enough experience with English using Stanford core nlp package.

I want to for non-english language like Arabic, how can I parse sentence using this package? Any example with command?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example command that should work:

```
java -Xmx3g -cp "*:." edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -maxLength 50 -tLPP edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ArabicTreebankParserParams -encoding UTF-8 -arabicFactored -tokenized -writeOutputFiles -outputFilesExtension out -outputFormat "penn" -loadFromSerializedFile edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/arabicFactored.ser.gz sample_arabic_sentence.txt
```

You will need to make sure you have the jar with the parser models:

stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar

This is available via Maven or with the parser distribution:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml